# Нужна ли запятая (см. всю фразу)?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом?

Вот, держи, как и договаривались(,) и не только...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Вот, держи, как и договаривались, **и не только...***

Здесь ***И*** — **присоединительный** союз, нет явно обозначенных однородных отношений, как при соединительном союзе ***И.***

Сравнить: *Вот, держи, что обещал **и не только**..*.  Здесь однородные отношения с местоимением ***ЧТО***.

[Запятая перед «и не только»](https://popravilam.com/blog/203-i-ne-tolko-zapyataya.html)

[Выделять ли запятыми "и не только"?](https://dzen.ru/a/YOaiVLANKzABkI37)

[Грамота об "и только"](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/i-tolko)